# How do I grow back to human size?

Tags: tales-from-the-minus-lab

I am playing Tales from the Minus Lab and I got the bridge to the tree to open but for some reason I cannot grow to the human size again. Do any of you guys have an idea what to do?

Comment: I figured out that you must click certain button configuration i think it was 3 or ctr +3 something silly like that but i forgot which buttons i must press and dont remember where i found the answer. -.-